# Handle a list of String

Tags: java, string, list, loops, java-stream

I have a list of String, I need to find all duplicates, also remove all children if the parents are in the list.
My string can have a max 4 levels:
Level0: "Root", or leave empty
Level1: "Sweden", "America", etc...
Level2: "Sweden.Stockholm", "America.Chicago", etc...
Level3: "Sweden.Stockholm.Solna", "America.Chicago.Cicero", etc...

So if I have a list `["Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden.Stockholm.Solna", "America.Chicago", "America.Chicago", "America.Chicago.Cicero"]` then only `["Sweden", "America.Chicago"]` should be returned.

How to do this with Java, preferably java 8 stream API?

The following 2 methods might be used to check if a String is a parent or child of another String:

```
private boolean isChildOf(String parentPath, String path) {
   return path.startsWith(parentPath.isBlank() ? parentPath : parentPath + ".") && !path.equals(parentPath);
}
```

```
private boolean isParentOf(String childPath, String path) {
   return childPath.startsWith(path + ".") && !path.equals(childPath);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the entry `Sweden.Stockholm.Solna` can come after `Sweden`?

Comment: Yes, the String list can be in any order.

Comment: What happens if one of the duplicates is a child (or parent) of another duplicate? If `Sweden.Stockholm.Solna` appeared twice in the original list, then would the resulting list contain only `America.Chicago`?

Comment: My understanding of the OP's request is that it only returns the uppermost parents, regardless of if there are any duplicates. However, the resulting list should not contain duplicates.

Comment: No, even if Sweden.Stockholm.Solna appears twice in the original list, the result should still be ["Sweden", "America.Chicago"]

Comment: @FlowerHill  What if the original list contains no duplicates but does contain prefixes of other entries along with unique entries?  Should `Sweden, Sweden.StockHolm.Solna, America.Chicago` also return  `Sweden, America.Chicago`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using sets. This will work with any depth of the hierarchy.

- first add the list to a set. This removes duplicates as they aren't needed.
- then iterate over a copy of that set and remove each element

  - if the current element is not equal to the element under test
  - and the current element starts with the element under test.

```
List<String> hierarchy = List.of(
       "Sweden.Stockholm.Solna", "America.Chicago", "America.Chicago",
       "America.Chicago.Cicero", "Sweden.Stockholm.Solna","Sweden", "Sweden");

Set<String> set = nodes.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

for (String str : new HashSet<>(set)) {
    set.removeIf(v -> !v.equals(str) && v.startsWith(str+"."));
}

set.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Sweden
America.Chicago
```

Comment: I realized that this solution will not work if the String are like "Sweden_abc.Stockholm" and "Sweden_abc". Then it will think the "Sweden_abc.Stockholm" is also a child of "Sweden".

Comment: @FlowerHill Excellent point!  I modifed the answer to ensure there is a "." in the `startsWith` call.  I would be interested in knowing if it solves the issue in your cases.

Comment: Now it works perfectly with this edge case, thanks!:)

Answer (score 0):

Provided correctness of isChildOf method, a nested loop checking every element against every other element in the list (except the current element) should solve the problem.

First remove duplicates

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(set);
```

Then remove children

```
for(string child : list) {
    for(string parent : list) {
       if (isChildOf(Parent, Child)):
          list.remove(Child)
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the OP's requirements but as I see it, the resulting list should first contain **only** duplicates, so if the original list contains **no** duplicates, then the resulting list should be an empty list and I don't see that your solution achieves that.

Comment: @Abra My take was a list of unique values such that none is the prefix of any other would return the entire list.  Duplicates only show down the process.  The OP did not specify what was meant by `find the duplicates`,

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation that I tested and is working as desired.

```
//initialize list from example
List<String> nodes = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden.Stockholm.Solna", "America.Chicago", "America.Chicago", "America.Chicago.Cicero"});
//sort into map grouped by the root level of the entries (regardless of if the "root" exists in list or not)
Map<String, List<String>> groups = nodes.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> isRoot(s) ? s : s.substring(0, s.indexOf(".")), Collectors.toList()));
//since they are already sorted by the root, we can just return the shortest string in each list
List<String> parents = groups.entrySet().stream().map(e -> getParent(e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(parents);
```

And here are the custom methods I used

```
//return the shortest String in the list
private String getParent(List<String> nodes) {
    return nodes.stream().min(Comparator.comparingInt(s -> s.length())).get();
}

private boolean isRoot(String s) {
    return !s.contains(".");
}
```

Edit: As the OP has already accepted the answer, I will leave the previous implementation. However, as was pointed out in comments, this solution misses cases where some parent elements share the same root level. I have modified my implementation to accommodate for this. No changes were necessary for `List<String> nodes` or `Map<String, List<String>> groups`, so I will only post the revised `List<String> parents` and the new helper method.

```
List<String> parents = groups.entrySet().stream().distinct().map(e -> {
        List<String> set = e.getValue();
        int min = set.stream().mapToInt(s -> numLevels(s)).min().getAsInt();
        return set.stream().distinct().filter(s -> numLevels(s) == min).toList();
    }).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

numLevels method

```
private static int numLevels(String s) {
    return (int)s.chars().filter(i -> i == (int)'.').count();
}
```

The new implementation uses `distinct` to remove duplicates. Then for each list entry in the `groups` map, it determines the minimum number of levels (using the number of occurrences of `.`) and returns a filtered list of elements that meet the criteria. Finally it flattens the results into a single list.

Comment: I like this solution the most, thx!

Comment: Hmm, valid point. Seems the solution works for the OP’s circumstance, but edge cases do exist which are not covered.

Comment: I presume you were responding to my comment which I removed because  of the duplicate crriteria in the question which made me rethink my comment.  My take was that if any entry, duplicate or not, is a prefix of other entries, then the others should be ignored.  The OP said they wanted to find duplicates but it wasn't clear to me what was meant by that since they aren't  specified as such in the ops result.

Comment: I think the intent was just to eliminate duplicates. Such that, in the example, it only prints `Sweden` once instead of 3 times. But you are right that my solution has cases that are not covered. For example, say we have `US.California` and `US.Utah` in the array. From my understanding, both should be returned because the root element `US` is not listed, but in my current implementation it will only return `US.Utah` because it is the shortest. I have an idea to correct this and should be updating shortly.

Comment: @CalvinP. I agree.  In general  I assumed that any list where any value is not a prefix of any other value in the list would return the entire list.

Comment: I missed the corner case as well, thx for pointing out and for the updated solution.:)

Answer (score 0):

**Create a new list to get all the duplicates**

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
List<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<String>();
list.forEach(word -> {
            
    if(!set.add(word))
        duplicates.add(word);

});
```

**Create another list to get all the childs**

```
List<String> childs = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String child : duplicates) {
    for(String parent : duplicates) {
       if (isChildOf(parent, child))
           childs.add(child);
    }
}
```

**Remove all childs from the duplicates**

```
duplicates.removeAll(childs);
```

Final `duplicates` is what you want as your final outcome.